# How to format/wipe emulator's SDCARD(/mnt/sdcard)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just want to know how to wipe the virtual sdcard in the android emulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the sdcard form the AVD manager and add a new one!?

Comment: LOL! so simple that i didn't think about this. Thank you. :D :D

Comment: Well, it's actually not simple and should be no problem to be included somewhere in the sdk more easily.

Comment: it's more easy to format or erase sdcard than above in emulator or divice. Go to `"Settings-> Storage -> Erase SD card"`

Answer (score 11):

With the expected caveats and warnings about using commands in the "rm -r *" family, you can also use: `adb -e shell rm -r /mnt/sdcard/*`

Comment: I've been trying for weeks to find a way to get the gallery to work again. It would constantly crash on my original galaxy tab 7". This fixed it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 8):

You can do it easily from Android Settings app: "Storage"->"Erase SD card".

Answer (score 1):

You could try deleting this file: sdcard.img in the emulator directory.  That's where it stores the info.

Just rename at first it in case it crashes things.  I haven't tested this before.

Comment: This does not work. SD-Card is then unavailable. However, if you copy the original empty one before it is used you can easily switch to an empty SD-Card by renaming.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch the emulator there's a checkbox to wipe user data.

Comment: this just removes the user data, not the sdcard data!Anyway, i tried it and doesn't work. Any other options ?

Comment: should be downvoted as it does NOT delete SD card as of original question

Answer (score 0):

Store your android avd data into a separate dir and just delete the dir and recreate the avd:

```
rm -rf $TMPDIR
install -d $TMPDIR
$android create avd --force --target "$target" --name $avdname \
    --sdcard 32M --skin WVGA800 --path $TMPDIR
emulator -avd $avdname -wipe-data -qemu -enable-kvm ...
```

That way, you make sure that you always start from an at least somewhat consistent state.