# How can remove emulator sdcard below folder in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sdcard, terminal-emulator

I am implementing sdcard related application. How can I remove emulator sdcard below folder in android using sqlite in devtools?

I am using rm command but it's not working:

Example: sdcard--->project --->emp

Delete project folder using terminal controller in-built sqlite

Comment: Check this thread... 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628393/how-to-format-wipe-emulators-sdcard-mnt-sdcard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the below steps to remove the sdcard folder of your emulator:

1. open the command prompt
2. go to the directory where your android sdk --> platform-tools
3. type adb shell
4. type cd sdcard
5. type rmdir "folder name"