# How to remove file that is saved on the SDCard of the Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard

In my application I am going to store the file from assets to the SDCard. But now there is no more space in the emulator. So I want to delete that file.

So how to delete that file from the Emulator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628393/how-to-format-wipe-emulators-sdcard-mnt-sdcard

Comment: I want to remove it By Manualy. ..

Comment: You can delete file using Eclipse "File explorer" tab for that emulator.

Comment: I know that i am able to see the file using file explorer, but i am not able to delete that file. How to delete that perticular file ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Option 1:

Go to Avd folder in

Windows XP

C:\Documents and Settings{current user}.android\avd{avd name}\

Vista/Win7

C:\Users{current user}.android\avd{avd name}\

Delete the **sdcard.img** file... when you run the emulator next time, it will create new sdcard

Option 2:

If you want to delete specific files from sdcard then

Open your command prompt and type

> adb shell
>
> cd \mnt\sdcard
>
> rm {filename}

Answer (score 4):

You can do this from DDMS. Ensure your emulator is running.

1. Go to DDMS perspective in eclipse.
2. In the Devices window select your emulator
3. Then go to Window-->Show View-->FIle Explorer
4. Open the sdcard folder and delete the files you want.